# Recursion Matlab: Saving the output in a vector/array

Tags: matlab

Im working on a school project and got a problem when using MATLAB recursively.
Basically, each time a recursion finishes, I want to save (x, y) coordinates that I find through the recursion in the order they are found, as a vector/array. Then I want to save all the arrays found in another vector/array.

In short I want to find:

```
ArrayWithArrays(ArrayWithArrayWithXY)(XY coordinates)
```

And the output I get from the recursive function is the XY coordinates in order
Is this possible using MATLAB?

Please tell me if you need me to be more specific.

Thank you for any answers.

Comment: Do you want to store the results of each step in the recursive solution or just the final results of multiple separate calls to a recursive function?

Comment: The goal is to find a path consisting of coordinates. I want to store each coordinate along the way to target coodinate from a start coordinate, ordered by the first coordinate first, then the second, and so on until the target is reached.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how many times your function iterates. If you don't know, use a maximum preset otherwise matlab will complain about allocations. The vector will be longer after each iteration so it needs a new memory location. Here for example n iterations:

`vector=zeros(n,2);
vector(1,:)=[startx,starty];`

now for example a simple function

```
for i=2:n
    vector(i,:)=[newcoorx,newcoory];
end
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer

Another problem is that the the recursive alghoritm finds many paths, and i only want the ones reaching the target destination. So i want each coordinate in theese path reacing the target. 

To specify further: the recursion runs until all possible paths are found. Many of the paths wont lead to the target, but I want to save  the ones that do.

I think  i have to use some kind of tracking as out/input( :-) ) to the recursive function, to determine the right paths that reach the target along with all the coordinates on the way.